# Go generics: Invalid composite literal

Tags: go, generics

The following code results in the error "invalid composite literal type T".

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(createThing[foo]())
}

type thing interface {
    foo | bar
}

type foo struct {
    id int
    a  string
}

type bar struct {
    id int
    b  int
}

func createThing[T thing, P *T]() P {
    return &T{}
}
```

If I only include `foo` in interface `thing`, or remove `a string` and `b int` so `foo` and `bar` are exactly the same, the code will run without error. However, doesn't this defeat the purpose of generics? Why can't I instantiate a generic type like this, especially when I'm not even accessing any fields?

Possibly related to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most generic types are not valid types for composite literals. This isn't a problem though, as there are other ways to create values of generic types.

To create a pointer to a new zero value:

```golang
func createThing[T thing]() *T {
    return new(T)
}
```

Or to create a non-pointer zero value:

```golang
func createThing[T thing]() T {
    var value T
    return value
}
```

As for *why* the error occurs in this way, here's the explanation from the spec, revised to address your specific question.

For [composite literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> The LiteralType's core type T must be a struct, array, slice, or map type

What is the [core type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Core_types)?

> An interface T has a core type if [...] there is a single type U which is the underlying type of all types in the type set of T
>
> No other interfaces have a core type.

What is the [underlying type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types)?

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its declaration.

A "type literal" can refer to a literal struct type, like `struct{int id}`. So, when `foo` and `bar` both have an **underlying type** of `struct{int id}`, then `thing` has a **core type** of `struct{int id}`, and so composite literals are possible. When `foo` and `bar` don't have the same underlying type, then `thing` has no core type, and composite literals are not possible, hence your error.

The formal definition may seem complicated, but the result and practical takeaway is simple: generic code is only capable of expressing common behaviour across the possible types. Besides in the special case where all underlying types are the same, literal values are not a common behaviour.