# why golang generic type not work for struct with different field

Tags: go

```golang
type A struct {
    x int
}

type B struct {
        // x int   // this is ok
        x string // this comes error below

}

func testG[T A | B]() T {
    t := T{} // err: invalid composite literal type T
    return t
}

func main() {
    testG[A]()
}
```

when `x int` in B, it's ok,

when `x string` in B, error happens: `invalid composite literal type T`

the difference is only the type x (string / int), how that happens, and why.

hope get some help, thks

Comment: when `B`'s field is `x int`, both `A` and `B` have the same underlying type, hence `T` constrained by `A | B` has a [core type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Core_types); when `B`'s field is `x string` `A` and `B` do *not* have the same underlying type, hence `T` constrained by `A | B` has *no* core type. Composite literals are valid if the type has a core type.

Comment: [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045168/go-generics-invalid-composite-literal) is as good an explanation as it gets

Comment: `var t T; return t` should work in both cases.